# Pass arguments to controller constructor by directive

Tags: angularjs

Has anyone ever needed to pass arguments to a controller constructor?

My controller:

```
angular.module("chatbotApp")
.directive('metadataZendesk', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            pass: "=",
            some: "@",
            properties: "="
        },
        botId: 1,
        templateUrl: 'views/account/bot/marketplace/modal.account.bot.zendesk.html',
        controller: 'AccountBotMarketplaceZendeskModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
          botId: 1,
        },
    };
}]);
```

To Controller:

'use strict';

```
angular
  .module('chatbotApp')
  .controller(
    'AccountBotMarketplaceZendeskModalCtrl',
    function (
      $scope,
      $translate,
      $timeout,
      accountBotService,
      botId,
      FeatureFlagValidation
    ) {
      $scope.zendeskIsValid = false;

    
    }
  );
```

Need pass botId to controllers, since resolve or passing with variables is not working and giving me a an error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: botIdProvider <- botId <- AccountBotMarketplaceZendeskModalCtrl
```

since this controller already exists in a swangular, i want to reuse to create a component with this same code.

thanks.